# Cypress generates outdated code for Google Authenticator

Tags: google-authentication, cypress, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Starting cypress ui test between (20..30) or (50..60) second of the minute causes wrong Google 2 factor token generation. It generates prevoious token.

Here is my token generation function:

```
function getToken () {
  const totp = require('totp-generator');
  const token = totp('2CQQGPPYFE7JPJAX');
  return token;
}
```

Here is how i get token before using it:

```
let token = getToken()
```

It looks like the token is generated on the beginning of the test (even if the call is in the middle of the test), and token is outdated at the time of it's usage, because new period has started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

Use promise function.

```
describe('check the tokens', function() 
{
// on 25 seconds 
it('Test first token ',()=> {
    cy.wait(25000).then(()=>{
        let token = getToken();
        console.log('first token: ' + token);
    })
})
// on 55 seconds 
it('Test second token', ()=>{
    cy.wait(30000).then(()=>{
        let token = getToken();
        console.log('second token: '+ token);
    });
})
})

function getToken () {
    const totp = require('totp-generator');
    const token = totp('2CQQGPPYFE7JPJAX');
    return token;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This particular code works as expected, but syntax is not clear for me. Before generating token I need to go through authorisation.

Comment: ```it('cy.window() - get the global window object', () => {
        cy.viewport(500, 780)
        cy.visit('https://site.domain',)
        cy.get('input[name=email]').type('email@server.io')
        cy.get('input[name=password]').focus().type('qwerty123')
        cy.get('.Button').click()
        //i need to get token here, because authorisation may take some time```

Comment: The code can be added right after your authorisation. cypress command will be executed one by one. So after you got the button clicked the cy.wait will execute after.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that plain TS lines go in parallel, while cy. commands go one by one.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid hard waits**
I would use an element on the page instead of a millisecond wait.

```js
describe('check the tokens', function() 
{
// First test 
it('cy.window() - get the global window object', () => { cy.viewport(500, 780) 
  cy.visit('https://site.domain',) 
  cy.get('input[name=email]').type('email@server.io') 
  cy.get('input[name=password]').focus().type('qwerty123') 
  cy.get('.Button').click()
  // Now lets wait on an object that appears on the page 
  // when ready to input the token
    cy.get(<someElement>).then(()=>{
        let token = getToken();
        console.log('first token: ' + token);
    })
})
//Second test
it('cy.window() - get the global window object', () => { cy.viewport(500, 780) 
  cy.visit('https://site.domain',) 
  cy.get('input[name=email]').type('email@server.io') 
  cy.get('input[name=password]').focus().type('qwerty123') 
  cy.get('.Button').click()
  // Now lets wait on an object that appears on the page 
  // when ready to input the token
    cy.get(<someOtherElement>).then(()=>{
        let token = getToken();
        console.log('second token: '+ token);
    });
})
})

function getToken () {
    const totp = require('totp-generator');
    const token = totp('2CQQGPPYFE7JPJAX');
    return token;
  }
```

**More advanced**
Even better than waiting on an element would be waiting on a network event or method to be called... https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias